# 1980s or early 90s horror movie featuring a sasquatch/bigfoot/yeti

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I've been searching for this movie for many years now. I was born in 1989 and I was under 10 years old when I watched it on TV, so I assume it's a movie from the 80s or early 90s.

I'm gonna describe TWO scenes; as I said, I was just a kid, so I can't be sure they are both from the same movie.

1. I remember a motorhome with some sort of group of scientists / students / explorers searching for something. And at some point, one of them was outside the trailer and the ones inside were monitoring his position with a radio and through a screen like a radar. When something gets really close to him on the screen, I remember them saying: "IT'S RIGHT THERE! IT'S RIGHT IN FRONT OF YOU." And the guy outside says: "THERE'S NOTHING HERE, I'M ALONE." Because it was in a deep forest, and all he could see was trees and leaves. I'm pretty sure it was during the day.
2. I remember an older man, taking a dump at one of those "toilets" that were outside of the house, like a small wooden shack (again, at daylight). He sits, opens a newspaper, then starts hearing footsteps outside. Then the creature's furry arm comes through the door and tries to grab him. They "wrestle" a little and the scene cuts. A few scenes later, it cuts back to the man telling his wife what happened while she washes him with a water hose from a distance, giving the impression that he was covered in shit because of the struggle.

That's it guys, it's all I remember. I'll be forever grateful if anyone can help me find this movie (if it really is just one). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8):

Is this ***[Boggy Creek II: And the Legend Continues](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088772/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1984)...?

> A professor and three of his students camp out in the wilderness to find a Bigfoot-type creature.

At around 32 minutes into the runtime, the aforementioned professor explains to his students that they're going to set up sensors in the forest around their campsite, so that they can monitor the entire area. They have a computer monitor with a radar-like display on it in a tent.

The professor initially sends two of the students out into the forest to test the equipment, but at around 37 minutes into the runtime, he takes the place of one of the students and tells her to head back to the camp. Another student in the tent with the computer monitor then tells him via a walkie-talkie that the creature is close to him, but he can't see it and asks whether it's to the left or the right. The creature doesn't actually attack in that scene, which takes place during daylight.

At around 46 minutes into the runtime, a middle-aged man is sitting in an outhouse when he hears the creature approaching. He initially thinks it's his wife, but then a fur-covered arm reaches in tries to grab him, and he inadvertently steps into the pit latrine trying to avoid it. The scene then cuts to his wife inside their bungalow, who hears him yelling and comes out to investigate. The creature is gone by the time she gets there, but her husband, while uninjured, now has a leg covered in excrement. She uses a hose to wash it off.

Comment: This film got the [Mystery Science Theater 3000](https://shout-tv.com/videos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=submit&q=boggy) treatment as well... IIRC they had a good time with the outhouse scene.

Comment: "For a transcript of the poop scene, send $2.99 to Journal Graphics."